# Select sum amount between ID range SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (Accounts) like:

```
ACC_ID   Description   ID_1         ID_2       ID_3     ID_4         AMOUNT
100070   INFO1                                                       1236.90
100150   INFO2                                                       1000.00
100170   INFO3                                                       2876.15
100180   INFO4                                                       3549.20
100360   INFO5         100001       100360                           NULL
110080   INFO6                                                       NULL
300010   INFO7                                                       -1418.74
300015   INFO8         100070       300015     400000   710000       NULL
400000   INFO9                                                       NULL                                    
400090   INFO10                                                      1245.00
700500   INFO11        400000       700500                           NULL
```

What I'm trying to do is sum the amount when the amount is null and the IDS has values, the values stored on the IDS means to start and finish (range) specified.

Having in mind that the new column will be called Total, the output will be something like=

```
ACC_ID      Description      Amount        Total
100070      INFO1            1236.90
100150      INFO2            1000.00
100170      INFO3            2876.15
100180      INFO4            3549.20
100360      INFO5            NULL          8662.25
110080      INFO6            NULL
300010      INFO7            -1418.74
300015      INFO8            NULL          8488.51
400000      INFO9            NULL
400090      INFO10           1245.00
400090      INFO11           NULL          1245.00
```

Note: When the Amount is null and All the IDs has value range specified then 
   the Formula would be something like :
   SUM(ID_1,ID_2) + SUM(ID_3,ID_4)

This is the SQL Code I'm using but is not working and it doesn't even include the formula when there 4 IDs with values.

```
SELECT ACC_ID, Description, Amount, CASE 
WHEN Amount IS NULL THEN CASE 
          WHEN ACC_ID BETWEEN ID_1 AND ID_2 THEN SUM(Amount)
END 
ELSE Amount
END TOTAL FROM CTE GROUP BY ACC_ID,Amount,Description,ID_1,ID_2 ORDER BY 
ACC_ID
```

Any assistance or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ACC_ID, Description, Amount, 
(CASE WHEN Amount IS NULL THEN
    CASE WHEN ID_1 !='' AND ID_2 !='' AND ID_3 ='' THEN
            (SELECT SUM(Amount)
            FROM CTE
            WHERE ACC_ID <= x.ID_2 and ACC_ID >= x.ID_1)
         WHEN ID_1 !='' AND ID_2 !='' AND ID_3 !='' AND ID_4 !='' THEN
            (SELECT SUM(Amount)
            FROM CTE
            WHERE ACC_ID <= x.ID_2 and ACC_ID >= x.ID_1 OR ACC_ID >= x.ID_3 and ACC_ID <= x.ID_4)
    END
 END) AS Total
FROM CTE x
ORDER BY ACC_ID;
```

Another version with some assumed validation for requiring both ID_1 and ID_2 or 1/2 and 3/4

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2ed80/6

Comment: got an error code for me? otherwise I can just delete my answer. I am not horribly invested in fixing it tbh

Comment: Fixed and added a fiddle for you

Comment: Working!, but the one that has values for all IDs doesn't retrieve nothing.

Comment: whoops! That is supposed to be an OR in between 1/2 and 3/4

Comment: Working great!! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you want window functions:

```
SELECT ACC_ID, Description, Amount,
       (CASE WHEN Amount IS NULL AND (ID_1 IS NOT NULL OR ID_2 IS NOT NULL OR ID_3 IS NOT NULL OR ID_4 IS NOT NULL)
             THEN SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY ACC_ID)
        END) as Total
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY ACC_ID;
```

Comment: I'm not even sure the ID_# column checks are needed, and it looks like they'd be `''` instead of `null`.

Comment: It work but somethings when the amount is null above or below the one that has values for the IDs is also filling those space with the same amount when it shouldn't and also when there is no values for the IDs is doing the calculation.

Comment: Yes you are right @scsimon the ID_# in the query should be <>' ' instead of Null, but now the only issue is for the one that has values for all of the IDs.

Comment: @JCACERES . . . This should only be showing the results when `Amount` is `NULL` (the `WHEN` condition).  If multiple rows in a row have ids, then the total will show for all those rows.  The `OVER (ORDER BY ACC_ID)` should not be getting any data from rows with a higher `ACC_ID`.